# HTML ng-controller (dropdown menu) working locally and on JSFiddle but not on Google Sites

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My HTML website with ng-app is working locally and on certain coding websites like JSFiddle and CodePen, but not on Google Sites, Github, W3, etc.

The intention is that you can choose a language (selected) from the dropdown menu in the script portion, and a corresponding paragraph will appear based off the selection (selected['paragraph']). However, on Google Sites, nothing is in or can be selected from the dropdown menu, and the website just displays `{{selected['paragraph']}}` directly as text.

Code below and in the plunker (where it works): https://plnkr.co/edit/k4YBCyw95wI6fxac?open=index.html; thank you in advance!

```
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function langCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.prop = {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Language",
        "values": [{
          id: 1,
          'lang': "ENGLISH",
          'paragraph': "insert english here"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          'lang': "KOREAN",
          'paragraph': "insert korean here"
        }, {
          id: 3,
          'lang': "SPANISH",
          'paragraph': "insert spanish here"
        }]
      };
      $scope.selected = $scope.prop.values[0]
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="langCtrl">
    <h1>
    </h1>
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="v.lang for v in prop.values">
    </select>
    <p>
    {{selected['paragraph']}}
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the controller to your app:

```
 <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller("langCtrl",function($scope) {
          $scope.prop = {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "Language",
        "values": [{
          id: 1,
          'lang': "ENGLISH",
          'paragraph': "insert english here"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          'lang': "KOREAN",
          'paragraph': "insert korean here"
        }, {
          id: 3,
          'lang': "SPANISH",
          'paragraph': "insert spanish here"
        }]
      };
      $scope.selected = $scope.prop.values[0]
    });
  </script>
```